# Un boton termina el bucle y el otro boton hace continuar el bucle, Ciclo Do While

Tags: java, android

Mi app consta de un ciclo "Do While" y dos botones, quiero que al tocar el primer boton (terminar), el ciclo termine y se ejecute el codigo del bucle. Pero altocar el otro boton (mas), el ciclo se reinicie y se repita el bucle. La app si realiza la accion del boton (terminar), pero al tocar el boton (mas), el bucle no continua (no se reinicia).

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalcularActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre_local;
    EditText nombre_visitante;
    EditText cuota_local;
    EditText cuota_visitante;
    EditText cuota_empate;

    Button mas;
    Button terminar;

    TextView fintext1;
    TextView fintext2;
    TextView fintext3;
    TextView fintext4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcular);

        nombre_local = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre_local);
        nombre_visitante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre_visitante);
        cuota_local = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_local);
        cuota_empate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_empate);
        cuota_visitante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_visitante);

        fintext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext1);
        fintext2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext2);
        fintext3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext3);
        fintext4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext4);

        mas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mas_partidos);
        terminar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);

        terminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Button siguiente = mas;

                do {

                    String local_0 = nombre_local.getText().toString();

                    String visita_0 = nombre_visitante.getText().toString();

                    double local = Double.parseDouble(cuota_local.getText().toString());

                    double empate = Double.parseDouble(cuota_empate.getText().toString());

                    double visita = Double.parseDouble(cuota_visitante.getText().toString());

                    double local_1 = 1 / local;
                    double empate_1 = 1 / empate;
                    double visita_1 = 1 / visita;

                    double suma_cuotas = local + empate + visita;

                    double local_2 = suma_cuotas - local;
                    double empate_2 = suma_cuotas - empate;
                    double visita_2 = suma_cuotas - visita;

                    double suma_cuotas2 = local_2 + empate_2 + visita_2;

                    double local_3 = local_2 / suma_cuotas2;
                    double empate_3 = empate_2 / suma_cuotas2;
                    double visita_3 = visita_2 / suma_cuotas2;


                    double local_4 = local_1 - local_3;
                    double empate_4 = empate_1 - empate_3;
                    double visita_4 = visita_1 - visita_3;

                    //VALOR ABSOLUTO
                    double local_5 = Math.abs(local_4);
                    double empate_5 = Math.abs(empate_4);
                    double visita_5 = Math.abs(visita_4);

                    fintext1.setText("\nPROBABILIDADES:\n" + local_0 + ":\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (local_1 * 100))) + "% , EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (local_3 * 100))) + "%\nEmpate:\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (empate_1 * 100))) + "% , EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (empate_3 * 100))) + "%\n" + visita_0 + ":\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (visita_1 * 100))) + "% ,EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (visita_3 * 100))) + "%");

                    fintext2.setText("\nPRONOSTICO:");



                    if ((local_4 - empate_5) > 0.11) {
                        fintext3.setText("\nGANA: " + local_0);
                    } else if ((visita_4 - empate_5) > 0.11) {
                        fintext3.setText("\nGANA: " + visita_0);
                    } else if ((local_4 - empate_5) < 0.11 && (local_4 - empate_5) > 0 && ((local_4 + empate_4) > (empate_4 + visita_4))) {
                        fintext3.setText("\nGANA O EMPATA: " + local_0);
                    } else if ((visita_4 - empate_5) < 0.11 && (visita_4 - empate_5) > 0 && ((visita_4 + empate_4) > (empate_4 + local_4))) {
                        fintext3.setText("\nGANA O EMPATA: " + visita_0);
                    } else {
                        fintext3.setText("\nPartido muy parejo: EMPATE");
                    }

                    fintext4.setText("_______________");


                } while (siguiente == terminar);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Crear un bucle while en una GUI es muestra de un mal diseño ya que las tareas sincronas(do-while) tienen mayor prioridad que las tareas sincronas(evento  onClick), por lo que te recomiendo rediseñar, ¿por qué usas un do-while?

Comment: ¿De que otra manera lo haria?, quiero que al tocar el boton "mas", el bucle continue y el usuario me vuelta a ingresar otros datos y asi hasta tocar el boton "terminar", donde quiero que me muestre todas las operaciones totales realizadas, si no es con Do While? como mas lo haria?

Comment: En una GUI solo debes hacer *la tarea* cuando suceda algun evento, por ejemplo la tarea la deberias realizar cuando suceda algun cambio en los  `EditText`s, y solo usar le boton para activar para cambiar un flag. ¿si no hay cambios en los EditText tendria sentido modificar la salida?

Comment: Por eso uso Do While, ya que si o si tendria que haber cambios en los EditText

Comment: Te voy a mostrar un ejemplo de la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: Seria lo mejor, gracias

Comment: Pero de antesala te recomiendo revisar informacion sobre Programación Orientada a Eventos

Comment: ¿Por qué no guardas la información en un array por ejemplo, en un map  o en otro objeto de tu preferencia y utilizas la información que haya en ese objeto cuando la necesites más adelante?

Comment: fijate si podes usar un runnable paraesa tarea...creo que un proceso en segundo plano va a hacer rendir mejor tu app

Comment: @JorgeLuisStark como ves no era necesario el while loop

Comment: Gracias, me fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu lógica de procesamiento no se debe hacer en todo instante, eso genera un gasto de recursos de forma innecesaria.

**¿Cuando se debe procesar?**

Cuando las entradas de tu proceso cambie, en tu caso cuando al menos uno de los valores de los EditText cambien, o cuando presiones el boton `mas`. Y ya no debe procesarse cuando se presione el boton terminar.

Para saber cuando hay algun cambio usamos la clase TextWatcher, asi que usando lo lógica anterior obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
public class CalcularActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{

    EditText nombre_local;
    EditText nombre_visitante;
    EditText cuota_local;
    EditText cuota_visitante;
    EditText cuota_empate;

    Button mas;
    Button terminar;

    TextView fintext1;
    TextView fintext2;
    TextView fintext3;
    TextView fintext4;

    boolean isEnabled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcular);

        nombre_local = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre_local);
        nombre_visitante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre_visitante);
        cuota_local = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_local);
        cuota_empate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_empate);
        cuota_visitante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuota_visitante);

        fintext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext1);
        fintext2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext2);
        fintext3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext3);
        fintext4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fintext4);

        mas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mas_partidos);
        terminar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);

        cuota_local.addTextChangedListener(this);
        cuota_empate.addTextChangedListener(this);
        cuota_visitante.addTextChangedListener(this);

        mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isEnabled = true;
                doProcess();
            }
        });

        terminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isEnabled = false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        doProcess();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }

    void doProcess() {
        if (isEnabled) {
            String local_0 = nombre_local.getText().toString();

            String visita_0 = nombre_visitante.getText().toString();

            double local = Double.parseDouble(cuota_local.getText().toString());

            double empate = Double.parseDouble(cuota_empate.getText().toString());

            double visita = Double.parseDouble(cuota_visitante.getText().toString());

            double local_1 = 1 / local;
            double empate_1 = 1 / empate;
            double visita_1 = 1 / visita;

            double suma_cuotas = local + empate + visita;

            double local_2 = suma_cuotas - local;
            double empate_2 = suma_cuotas - empate;
            double visita_2 = suma_cuotas - visita;

            double suma_cuotas2 = local_2 + empate_2 + visita_2;

            double local_3 = local_2 / suma_cuotas2;
            double empate_3 = empate_2 / suma_cuotas2;
            double visita_3 = visita_2 / suma_cuotas2;


            double local_4 = local_1 - local_3;
            double empate_4 = empate_1 - empate_3;
            double visita_4 = visita_1 - visita_3;

            //VALOR ABSOLUTO
            double local_5 = Math.abs(local_4);
            double empate_5 = Math.abs(empate_4);
            double visita_5 = Math.abs(visita_4);

            fintext1.setText("\nPROBABILIDADES:\n" + local_0 + ":\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (local_1 * 100))) + "% , EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (local_3 * 100))) + "%\nEmpate:\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (empate_1 * 100))) + "% , EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (empate_3 * 100))) + "%\n" + visita_0 + ":\nC.A__" + (String.format("%.2f", (visita_1 * 100))) + "% ,EST.__" + (String.format("%.2f", (visita_3 * 100))) + "%");

            fintext2.setText("\nPRONOSTICO:");


            if ((local_4 - empate_5) > 0.11) {
                fintext3.setText("\nGANA: " + local_0);
            } else if ((visita_4 - empate_5) > 0.11) {
                fintext3.setText("\nGANA: " + visita_0);
            } else if ((local_4 - empate_5) < 0.11 && (local_4 - empate_5) > 0 && ((local_4 + empate_4) > (empate_4 + visita_4))) {
                fintext3.setText("\nGANA O EMPATA: " + local_0);
            } else if ((visita_4 - empate_5) < 0.11 && (visita_4 - empate_5) > 0 && ((visita_4 + empate_4) > (empate_4 + local_4))) {
                fintext3.setText("\nGANA O EMPATA: " + visita_0);
            } else {
                fintext3.setText("\nPartido muy parejo: EMPATE");
            }

            fintext4.setText("_______________");
        }
    }
}
```